# NET I/O stats value missing inside GKE docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

facing some problem while using docker stats command in kubernetes.. While i using docker stats in my kube-node its not displaying the NET I/O.. My kube version is 1.2.4 and my docker version is 1.9.1.

CONTAINER              CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O

494ffcff748a             0.06%                508.2 MB / 7.864 GB      6.46%                  0 B / 0 B            106.4 MB / 5.841 MB

Particularly in GKE its not showing NET I/O. Do i need to enable anything to get this NET I/O values?..
Thanks Advance...

Answer (score 3):

There's a separate container that'll have the network stats for your entire pod, since all the containers in a pod share the same network namespace. If your container is named skydns and its pod is named kube-dns in the kube-system namespace (and thus the name of your skydns container looks something like `k8s_skydns.<short-hash>_kube-dns-v11-ulru9_kube-system_<hash>`), then there'll be another container called `k8s_POD.<short-hash>_kube-dns-v11-ulru9_kube-system_<hash>`, which the distinguishing characteristic being that it has the string POD where the container name typically goes.

There was a discussion explaining the purpose of the pause container on the Kubernertes email list here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/jVjv0QK4b_o

Comment: Alternatively, you can query kubelet directly for the pod stats: `curl http://localhost:10255/stats/summary`. It will show you per-pod stats, includieng the network I/O.